# Cannot define variables outside of a class's constructor function

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I am creating a normal ES6 class. The problem encountered is putting a variable inside the `class` encapsulation while keeping it outside of `constructor().`

You can replicate this error when you use this code:

```
class Polygon {  
     constructor() {
          this.name = "Polygon";

          var goodboy = "I like pie...I can stay since I'm legal!";
     }

     var badboy = "what're you gonna do when they come for you? delete me to get rid of all your problems!";

}

var poly1 = new Polygon();

console.log(poly1.name);
```

You can try this code anywhere! Try deleting `badboy` and `goodboy` and see how it plays out.

**How can I get around this?**

Any explanation is welcome,
Farouk

*Aforementioned code was modified from MDN. This code has no intention and is meant for variable declaration example purposes.*

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is no such thing as a "*`class` encapsulation*" in which you could put arbitrary statements. It's not a block, it's a `class` body and can only contain method definitions.

Comment: Enter the confusion caused by TypeScript (making JS look like Java).

Comment: What your trying to do does not really exist in Javascript yet, but it looks like it's on the way ->  https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

Answer (score 1):

You can declare class level variables like so

```
class Polygon {
    myVar = null;
    constructor(args){
       this.myVar = args.myVar;
    }
}
let polygon = new Polygon({myVar:"some value"});
console.log(polygon.myVar); // "some value"
```

To accomplish this by transpiling with Babel you will need to use [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) plugin.

Comment: Not sure why you got down voted here, but it might be because this is still at `stage 3`.   Maybe a mention that it's not yet standard Javascript may help..

Comment: Thanks...but I currently don't have access to Babel

Comment: this is a possible answer so upvote

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot define variables outside of a class's constructor function

Yes, that's not syntactically valid.

> I'm putting a variable inside the `class` encapsulation while keeping it outside of `constructor()`.

That's not possible. A `class` does not provide any such encapsulation, it does not create a block scope. Just put the variable outside of the `class` definition. Or don't make it a variable but a property instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
// adjusted
   class Polygon
   {
      constructor()
      {
         this.name = "Polygon";

        var goodboy = "I like pie...I can stay since I'm legal!";
      }
   }

   var poly = new Polygon();

   console.log(poly.name);

   // option 2 
   // This works also

   function Polygon2()
   {
      this.name = "Polygon";

      class Poly
      {
        constructor(obj)
        {
            this.user = "Farouk";
            this.name2 = obj.name;
        }
      }

      let poly2 = new Poly(this);

      this.user = poly2.user;
      this.name2 = poly2.name2;
   }

   var poly2 = new Polygon2();

   console.log(poly2.name);
   console.log(poly2.user);
   console.log(poly2.name2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, inside a class you can not declare a member directly, you need to use getter and setter. Otherwise you will get an error: "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected."

Here is how you can get your badboy:

```
class Polygon {

  constructor() {
    this.name = "Polygon";
  }

  get badboy(){
    return  "what're you gonna do when they come for you?";
  }
}

var poly1 = new Polygon();
console.log(poly1.name); // Polygon
console.log(poly1.badboy); // what're you gonna do when they come for you?
```

Intention of your code is not clear enough. If you will not use it as an instance property, why would you put it in a class?

You know `poly1.badboy = "what're you gonna do when they come for you?"` does the same thing without all the hassle.